# WPF - Refer to app icon in code

Tags: wpf

i have added an icon to a WPF app in the project properties.

How do I refer to that icon so I can add it to a
NotifyIcon that I am creating for system tray.

In code that is??

```
  System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon ni = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon();
  ni.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon("MyIcon.ico");
```

Does not work.
Malcolm

Answer (score 9):

```
System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon ni = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon();
ni.Icon = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(
             System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().ManifestModule.Name);
ni.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this may be what you are looking for:

[How do I use an icon that is a resource in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74466/how-do-i-use-an-icon-that-is-a-resource-in-wpf)

You need to embed the icon as a resource and then you can access it from code.