# How do I display a Windows file icon in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, icons

Currently I'm getting a native icon by calling SHGetFileInfo. Then, I'm converting it to a bitmap using the following code. The Bitmap eventually gets displayed in the WPF form.

Is there a faster way to do the same thing?

```
try
        {
            using (Icon i = Icon.FromHandle(shinfo.hIcon))
            {
                Bitmap bmp = i.ToBitmap();
                MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream();
                bmp.Save(strm, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                BitmapImage bmpImage = new BitmapImage();
                bmpImage.BeginInit();
                strm.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                bmpImage.StreamSource = strm;
                bmpImage.EndInit();

                return bmpImage;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Win32.DestroyIcon(hImgLarge);
        }
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
using System.Windows.Interop;

...

ImageSource img = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(
    shinfo.hIcon,
    new Int32Rect(0,0,i.Width, i.Height),
    BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
```

Answer (score 27):

How about something like:

```
var icon = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(fileName);
var bmp = icon.ToBitmap()
```

Comment: Clearly you're not being convoluted enough ;)

Comment: @Slomojo using System.Drawing and Bitmap map = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(fileName).ToBitmap() also works...

Comment: ToBitmap() loses the alpha channel

Comment: This only extracts icons at 32x32 resolution.

Comment: Instead of using `icon.ToBitmap()`, you can convert the icon directly to an ImageSource, using the `icon.Handle` property and Thomas or Krysztof answers. Or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6580799/752842)

Answer (score 11):

Combining [Krzysztof Kowalczyk answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325625/how-do-i-display-a-windows-file-icon-in-wpf#answer-3965827) with some googling, i made up this:

Method:

```
/*
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
*/

     public static ImageSource GetIcon(string strPath, bool bSmall)
        {
          Interop.SHFILEINFO info = new Interop.SHFILEINFO(true);
          int cbFileInfo = Marshal.SizeOf(info);
          Interop.SHGFI flags;
          if (bSmall)
            flags = Interop.SHGFI.Icon | Interop.SHGFI.SmallIcon | Interop.SHGFI.UseFileAttributes;
          else
            flags = Interop.SHGFI.Icon | Interop.SHGFI.LargeIcon | Interop.SHGFI.UseFileAttributes;

          Interop.SHGetFileInfo(strPath, 256, out info, (uint)cbFileInfo, flags);

          IntPtr iconHandle = info.hIcon;
          //if (IntPtr.Zero == iconHandle) // not needed, always return icon (blank)
          //  return DefaultImgSrc;
          ImageSource img = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(
                      iconHandle,
                      Int32Rect.Empty,
                      BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
          Interop.DestroyIcon(iconHandle);
          return img;
        }
```

and Interop class:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public static class Interop
  {
    /// <summary>Maximal Length of unmanaged Windows-Path-strings</summary>
    private const int MAX_PATH = 260;
    /// <summary>Maximal Length of unmanaged Typename</summary>
    private const int MAX_TYPE = 80;


    [Flags]
    public enum SHGFI : int
    {
      /// <summary>get icon</summary>
      Icon = 0x000000100,
      /// <summary>get display name</summary>
      DisplayName = 0x000000200,
      /// <summary>get type name</summary>
      TypeName = 0x000000400,
      /// <summary>get attributes</summary>
      Attributes = 0x000000800,
      /// <summary>get icon location</summary>
      IconLocation = 0x000001000,
      /// <summary>return exe type</summary>
      ExeType = 0x000002000,
      /// <summary>get system icon index</summary>
      SysIconIndex = 0x000004000,
      /// <summary>put a link overlay on icon</summary>
      LinkOverlay = 0x000008000,
      /// <summary>show icon in selected state</summary>
      Selected = 0x000010000,
      /// <summary>get only specified attributes</summary>
      Attr_Specified = 0x000020000,
      /// <summary>get large icon</summary>
      LargeIcon = 0x000000000,
      /// <summary>get small icon</summary>
      SmallIcon = 0x000000001,
      /// <summary>get open icon</summary>
      OpenIcon = 0x000000002,
      /// <summary>get shell size icon</summary>
      ShellIconSize = 0x000000004,
      /// <summary>pszPath is a pidl</summary>
      PIDL = 0x000000008,
      /// <summary>use passed dwFileAttribute</summary>
      UseFileAttributes = 0x000000010,
      /// <summary>apply the appropriate overlays</summary>
      AddOverlays = 0x000000020,
      /// <summary>Get the index of the overlay in the upper 8 bits of the iIcon</summary>
      OverlayIndex = 0x000000040,
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct SHFILEINFO
    {
      public SHFILEINFO(bool b)
      {
        hIcon = IntPtr.Zero;
        iIcon = 0;
        dwAttributes = 0;
        szDisplayName = "";
        szTypeName = "";
      }
      public IntPtr hIcon;
      public int iIcon;
      public uint dwAttributes;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = MAX_PATH)]
      public string szDisplayName;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = MAX_TYPE)]
      public string szTypeName;
    };

    [DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int SHGetFileInfo(
      string pszPath,
      int dwFileAttributes,
      out    SHFILEINFO psfi,
      uint cbfileInfo,
      SHGFI uFlags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool DestroyIcon(IntPtr hIcon);
  }
```

[source](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.SHGetFileInfo)

Comment: Copy / Paste Solution!... +1. Just a small comment though: You should stick with "BitmapSource" base instead of "ImageSource" as once promoted it is harder to cast back to the base class. Perfect Answer otherwise. Thanks.

Comment: Works perfectly. One improvement: Since loading icons for a number of files can take a moment, you might want to do it in a worker thread. To be able to use such an image in the UI, it must be frozen: `img.Freeze();` It won't change anyway.

Comment: Great solution. I extended it so that is also supports directories. Instead of passing the magic number 256 to SHGetFileInfo, I pass `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY` ( 0x10 ) when I want to retrieve the folder icon, `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL` ( 0x80 ) otherwise. I added these two values as constants inside the Interop class. Used information from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599235/how-do-i-fetch-the-folder-icon-on-windows-7-using-shell32-shgetfileinfo) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg258117(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 8):

Thomas's code could be simplified even more. Here's the full code with additional error checking:

```
            Interop.SHGetFileInfo(path, isFile, ref pifFileInfo);
            IntPtr iconHandle = pifFileInfo.hIcon;
            if (IntPtr.Zero == iconHandle)
                return DefaultImgSrc;
            ImageSource img = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(
                        iconHandle,
                        Int32Rect.Empty,
                        BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
            User32.DestroyIcon(iconHandle);
            return img;
```

The difference is:

- no need to create Icon object
- make sure to handle a case where iconHandle is 0 (IntPtr.Zero) by e.g. returning some pre-defined ImageSource object
- make sure to use win32 api DestroyIcon() if it comes from SHGetFileInfo()

Comment: Can you please provide the Interop code as well? I'm having problems matching your code with the function signature of SHGetFileInfo from the Windows API. All other solutions I have found use System.Drawing, which seems 100% incompatible with WPF, so why bother using it. This looks the most straight-forward. If I could get it to work.

Comment: Interop class & other combined in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325625/how-do-i-display-a-windows-file-icon-in-wpf#answer-29819585) below (its too long for comment)

Answer (score 1):

I belive there's simpler (more managed) way of solving this hilighted here.
http://www.pchenry.com/Home/tabid/36/EntryID/193/Default.aspx

The crux is of the solution is here.

```
System.Drawing.Icon formIcon = IconsInWPF.Properties.Resources.Habs;
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
formIcon.Save(stream);
this.Icon = BitmapFrame.Create(stream);
```

Comment: Remember to dispose your resources after using them. In this scenario, your stream is not closed I think.