# How do I fetch the folder icon on Windows 7 using Shell32.SHGetFileInfo

Tags: c#, .net, shell, windows-7

I have the following code which works on Windows XP and Vista - both 32 and 64 bit:

```
public static Icon GetFolderIcon(IconSize size, FolderType folderType)
{
    // Need to add size check, although errors generated at present!
    uint flags = Shell32.SHGFI_ICON | Shell32.SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES;

    if (FolderType.Open == folderType)
    {
        flags += Shell32.SHGFI_OPENICON;
    }

    if (IconSize.Small == size)
    {
       flags += Shell32.SHGFI_SMALLICON;
    } 
    else 
    {
       flags += Shell32.SHGFI_LARGEICON;
    }

    // Get the folder icon
    var shfi = new Shell32.SHFILEINFO();
    Shell32.SHGetFileInfo(  null, 
                            Shell32.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY, 
                            ref shfi, 
                            (uint) Marshal.SizeOf(shfi), 
                            flags );

    Icon.FromHandle(shfi.hIcon);    // Load the icon from an HICON handle

    // Now clone the icon, so that it can be successfully stored in an ImageList
    var icon = (Icon)Icon.FromHandle(shfi.hIcon).Clone();

    User32Dll.DestroyIcon( shfi.hIcon );        // Cleanup
    return icon;
}
```

The constants are defined the following way:

```
public const uint SHGFI_ICON = 0x000000100;
public const uint SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES = 0x000000010;
public const uint SHGFI_OPENICON = 0x000000002;
public const uint SHGFI_SMALLICON = 0x000000001;
public const uint SHGFI_LARGEICON = 0x000000000;
public const uint FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY = 0x00000010;
```

This gives the following results in windows 7 when fetching the folder icon:

[image]

While at Vista - using the same method result in the following folder icon:

[image]

I would like the "correct" Windows folder icon for Windows 7 also - not the icon used to indicate the drive where Windows is installed.

I don't know the win32 API and my non-managed programming is next to none on the Windows platform.

Comment: Please clarify your question. What does "This results in windows 7 with the following icons" mean?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You shouldn't specify `null` as yur first parameter to `SHGeFileInfo`. Use the path to a folder instead (please note that some folders have different (non-standard) icons). You could use the temp folder or your application's root folder for example.

Best practise would be to get the correct icon for each folder (in other words: Change the signature of `GetFolderIcon` to `public static Icon GetFolderIcon(string folderPath, IconSize size, FolderType folderType)` and call it for each folder you display).

There seems to be an open source library which already has a managed wrapper for fetching folder icons. 
Found on PInvoke.net (the entry for SHGetFileInfo):

> However, this does not work if you want an icon of a drive or folder.
>
> In that case, you can use the ExtendedFileInfo class provided by the ManagedWindowsApi project (http://mwinapi.sourceforge.net).

If you want to stick to a hand-crafted solution, this works for me (Win7 x64 RTM, .NET 3.5 SP1):

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace IconExtractor
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct SHFILEINFO
    {
        public IntPtr hIcon;
        public int iIcon;
        public uint dwAttributes;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
        public string szDisplayName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 80)]
        public string szTypeName;
    };

    public enum FolderType
    {
        Closed,
        Open
    }

    public enum IconSize
    {
        Large,
        Small
    }

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern IntPtr SHGetFileInfo(string pszPath, uint dwFileAttributes, out SHFILEINFO psfi, uint cbFileInfo, uint uFlags);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool DestroyIcon(IntPtr hIcon);

        public const uint SHGFI_ICON = 0x000000100; 
        public const uint SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES = 0x000000010; 
        public const uint SHGFI_OPENICON = 0x000000002; 
        public const uint SHGFI_SMALLICON = 0x000000001; 
        public const uint SHGFI_LARGEICON = 0x000000000; 
        public const uint FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY = 0x00000010;

        public static Icon GetFolderIcon(IconSize size, FolderType folderType)
        {    
            // Need to add size check, although errors generated at present!    
            uint flags = SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES;    

            if (FolderType.Open == folderType)    
            {        
                flags += SHGFI_OPENICON;    
            }    
            if (IconSize.Small == size)    
            {       flags += SHGFI_SMALLICON;    
            }     
            else     
            {       
                flags += SHGFI_LARGEICON;    
            }    
            // Get the folder icon    
            var shfi = new SHFILEINFO();    

            var res = SHGetFileInfo(@"C:\Windows",                             
                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY,                             
                out shfi,                             
                (uint) Marshal.SizeOf(shfi),                             
                flags );

            if (res == IntPtr.Zero)
                throw Marshal.GetExceptionForHR(Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error());

            // Load the icon from an HICON handle  
            Icon.FromHandle(shfi.hIcon);    

            // Now clone the icon, so that it can be successfully stored in an ImageList
            var icon = (Icon)Icon.FromHandle(shfi.hIcon).Clone();    

            DestroyIcon( shfi.hIcon );        // Cleanup    

            return icon;}

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                Icon icon = GetFolderIcon(IconSize.Large, FolderType.Open);
                pictureBox1.Image = icon.ToBitmap();
                // Note: The image actually should be disposed somewhere
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: because everyone has 'C:\Windows' on their system

Comment: It works even if you don't have 'C:\Windows', see Tom's answer. Anyway, that's why there is a remark on best practices and a "this works for me".

Answer (score 9):

> You shouldn't specify null as yur first parameter to SHGeFileInfo.

That's right.

> Use the path to a folder instead (please note that some folders have different (non-standard) icons). You could use the temp folder or your application's root folder for example.

It doesn't need to be a real (existing) folder path. Any non-empty string will do. e.g.:

```
SHGetFileInfo("AnyNonEmptyStringWillDo", FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY, sfi,
      SizeOf(sfi), SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES or SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX)
```

Comment: This is a very useful, and working, answer. You don't have to try to hunt around for a real folder to pass. In fact i literally pass `"AnyNonEmptyStringWillDo"`.