# File default Icon in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I display a Windows file icon in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325625/how-do-i-display-a-windows-file-icon-in-wpf)

I'm building email client using WPF. I display first the mail content with list of the attachments of the mail . I need a way to display thumbnail of the file so user can see what is the file about. For example, if it's an image then user can see the thumbnail like windows explorer , if its word then word default icon , in summary to display the list like windows explorer with the thumbnails .

Any ideas ?

Comment: +1; Oops.  I read further.  This is not actually a duplicate of that question, even if the question/answer might have the necessary code.  That question is for a code review, this question is on how to get the icon associated in the shell with a file type.

Comment: +1 and voting to reopen. Not only isn't it a duplicate, the OP isn't actually asking about the icon. OP is asking about a thumbnail like Windows Explorer shows for image files.