# How do I use standard Windows warning/error icons in my WPF app?

Tags: c#, wpf, icons

I'm making a custom error dialog in my WPF app and I want to use a [standard windows error icon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511277.aspx). Can I get the OS-specific icon from WPF? If not, does anyone know where to get .pngs with transparency of them? Or know where in Windows to go extract them from?

So far my searches have turned up nothing.

Comment: Do you want the same image regardless of platform, or do you want the icon corresponding to the current version of Windows (including future versions)?

Comment: Ideally, an icon that looks like the standard icon for that version of Windows. But I can settle for just getting the standard for Vista/7.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There is a [SystemIcons](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemicons.aspx) class, but it need adjustment for WPF needs (i.e. converting `Icon` to `ImageSource`).

Comment: You completely obviated the need for p/invoke.  Good call.

Comment: by the way, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127647/convert-system-drawing-icon-to-system-media-imagesource, this may help

Comment: That other thread has about four steps too many.  Use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.imaging.createbitmapsourcefromhicon(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(SystemIcons.Error.Handle, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions()); - Seems to work great, thanks!

Comment: Agreed.  Also, that other thread does show the CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon solution as well -- you just have to scroll down to see it (it isn't the accepted answer).

Answer (score 29):

The vast majority of developers out there don't know that Visual Studio comes with an Image Library. So here goes two links that highlight it:

About using [Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Image Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247035.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for that, but if I am not mistaked you have to cut out each icon by yourself. Ouch!

Comment: Note the image library no longer comes with Visual Studio, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20612263/1462295

Answer (score 26):

This is how I used a System icon in XAML:

```
xmlns:draw="clr-namespace:System.Drawing;assembly=System.Drawing"
...
<Image Source="{Binding Source={x:Static draw:SystemIcons.Warning},
        Converter={StaticResource IconToImageSourceConverter},
        Mode=OneWay}" />
```

I used this converter to turn an Icon to ImageSource:

```
public class IconToImageSourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var icon = value as Icon;
        if (icon == null)
        {
            Trace.TraceWarning("Attempted to convert {0} instead of Icon object in IconToImageSourceConverter", value);
            return null;
        }

        ImageSource imageSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(
            icon.Handle,
            Int32Rect.Empty,
            BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        return imageSource;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you also have a custom extension method called ToImageSource() ? I couldn't find anything built in that would do that.

Comment: Yes I forgot about that. I added the code from the extension method into the converter itself.

Comment: For error "IconToImageSourceConverter could not be resolved". The `converter` needs to be defined in the `FrameworkElement.Resource` element (i.e. Application, Window, UserControl). See SO answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/34351777/4962272](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34351777/4962272)

Answer (score 5):

In Visual Studio, use File + Open + File and select c:\windows\system32\user32.dll.  Open the Icon node and double-click 103.  On my machine that's the Error icon.  Back, right-click it and select Export to save it to a file.

That's the iffy way.  These icons are also available in Visual Studio.  From your Visual Studio install directory, navigate to Common7\VS2008ImageLibrary\xxxx\VS2008ImageLibrary.zip + VS2008ImageLibrary\Annotations&Buttons\ico_format\WinVista\error.ico.  The redist.txt file in the Visual Studio install directly explicitly gives you the right to use this icon in your own application.

Comment: Actually the unmanaged resource IDs are #defined in winuser.h and compiled into literally millions of programs by now.  So they aren't changing.  The index within the DLL, and even which DLL contains the system icons might change, but the resource ID never will.

Comment: @Ben: no, MB_ICONERROR has the value 0x10.  Not close to the resource ID.  Again: if you have special knowledge of how this works then, puhleze, post your own answer.

Comment: You seem determined to make everything personal rather than let each technical topic stand alone.  In this particular case, you might educate yourself by reading the answer I was typing as you posted yours and several hours before your comment.  The resource ID OIC_HAND or equivalently OIC_ERROR, which is used with the MAKEINTRESOURCE macro, hasn't changed since LoadImage was introduced and never can, since it's compiled into millions of programs.

Comment: sorry, I was mistaken about the intervening time.  It was just about one hour, not several hours before.

Answer (score 5):

- p/invoke [LoadImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648045(VS.85).aspx) with the OIC_ERROR ([other icons available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648045(VS.85).aspx#8), but you wanted the error/stop icon), you need the LR_SHARED flag.
- If you want a different size, p/invoke [CopyImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648031(v=VS.85).aspx)
- Call [System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.icon.fromhandle(v=VS.90).aspx) with the IntPtr you got from LoadImage
- For GDI+, [Draw your Drawing.Icon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66tzctxt.aspx), or [Clone it for later use](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.icon.clone(v=VS.90).aspx).
- For WPF, [turn it into a BitmapSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.imaging.createbitmapsourcefromhicon(v=VS.90).aspx)
- p/invoke [DestroyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648063(v=VS.85).aspx) if you used CopyImage

You can use .NET's SystemIcons class for roughly the first three steps if the default size is ok, see [modosansreves answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572734/how-do-i-use-standard-windows-warning-error-icons-in-my-wpf-app/2572799#2572799)

So it could be as simple as:

```
 Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(SystemIcons.Error.Handle)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

using Extensions
{
    [ContentProperty("Icon")]
    public class ImageSourceFromIconExtension : MarkupExtension
    {
        public Icon Icon { get; set; }

        public ImageSourceFromIconExtension()
        {
        }

        public ImageSourceFromIconExtension(Icon icon)
        {
            Icon = icon;
        }

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(Icon.Handle, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add System.Drawing reference to your project from global location.

Then use this in your xaml:

```
<WindowOrSomething x:Class="BlaBlaWindow"
    xmlns:draw="clr-namespace:System.Drawing;assembly=System.Drawing"
    xmlns:ext="clr-namespace:Extensions">
    <Image Source="{ext:ImageSourceFromIcon {x:Static draw:SystemIcons.Error}}"/>
</WindowOrSomething>
```

Answer (score 3):

Can't you simply use Windows API?

Delphi Example:

```
procedure TForm1.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  errIcon: HICON;
begin
  errIcon := LoadIcon(0, IDI_ERROR);
  DrawIcon(Canvas.Handle, 10, 10, errIcon)
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can draw it like this:

```
Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
g.DrawIcon(SystemIcons.Question, 40, 40);
```

Comment: ... no `Graphics` in WPF. What you wrote is for GDI.

Comment: GDI+ actually, but it's true that none of us have yet provided the conversion to a WPF image.  I'm not familiar with WPF but I'm sure someone knows how.

Answer (score 0):

use `SystemIcons` and convert them to an `ImageSource` like so:

```
try   
{
    var temp = SystemIcons.WinLogo.ToBitmap();  //Your icon here
    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
    {
       temp.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Png);
       memory.Position = 0;
       bitmapImage.BeginInit();
       bitmapImage.StreamSource = memory;
       bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
       bitmapImage.EndInit();
    }
    this.Icon = bitmapImage;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    this.Icon = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert SystemIcons.Error etc to .png (maintains transparency) then add output to resources and use as usual in WPF Image control.

```
    System.Drawing.SystemIcons.Error.ToBitmap().Save("Error.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```