# Can I use the system's default save/new/etc file icons in WPF?

Tags: wpf, icons

What I refer to by "system's default icons" are the open/new/save icons I see in applications like Office.

I wondered if I can somehow reference these, because they seem like standard icons. Or do I have to find those icons elsewhere and embed them into my applications?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2006/06/06/618797.aspx) by Brad Abrams back in 2006:

> A customer recently asked me if they can use the standard Microsoft explorer icons in their applications.  The answer is yes!  In fact Soma blogged about the extended set of [Icons we have in VS2005](http://blogs.msdn.com/somasegar/archive/2005/01/23/359124.aspx), but basically you can find the VS 2005 Image Library at %vs install path%/common7/ide/vs2005imagelibrary/vs2005imagelibrary.zip. The Windows, Office, and Visual Studio icons that we license for reuse are all contained in there.

Yes it's talking about VS 2005, but the same will apply for VS 2008 and VS 2010. For me (with VS 2008 on a 32 bit machine) the path is:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\VS2008ImageLibrary\1033\VS2008ImageLibrary.zip

I've just installed VS2010 and the path is:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\VS2010ImageLibrary\1033\VS2010ImageLibrary.zip

Comment: Great link! Did not know something like that is publicly available - although, obviously, it was on my hard drive already... :)

Comment: ooo ... i cant find it in VS2010

Comment: @jiewmeng - I don't have vs 2010 installed so I can't double check. You could try searching for "*imagelibrary.zip"

Comment: If you are on a 64-bit machine check: 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\VS2010ImageLibrary\1033\VS2010ImageLibrary.zip

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and the file isn't in that location for me (Win7 64bit VS Express 2010). Maybe it's not included with express. I checked both Program Files and Program Files (x86).

Comment: They appear to have finally dropped this package in VS 2012.

Answer (score 26):

For Visual Studio 2012 and later, the Visual Studio Image Library containing most of the icons can be downloaded from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35825 as they are no longer installed by default.

Comment: VS2013 icons are also there. And you're still allowed to redistribute them, see the EULA on the same page.