# How to bind to static BitmapSource?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-4.5

I'd like to create my custom error/exception dialog with the standard Windows "Error icon".

I followed the advice from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572734/how-do-i-use-standard-windows-warning-error-icons-in-my-wpf-app) and it works.

However I'm currently creating an instance property I bind to just like to any property:

```
class ErrorWindowViewModel
{
    private readonly ImageSource _errorImage;

    public ImageSource ErrorImage { get { return _errorImage; } }

    public ErrorWindowViewModel()
    {
        _errorImage = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(SystemIcons.Error.Handle, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
    }
}
```

What I'd like to do is to have a static field defined in my ErrorWindow class:

```
partial class ErrorWindow : Window
    {
        private readonly static ImageSource ErrorImage = 
            Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(SystemIcons.Error.Handle, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
    }
```

I can't force my XAML to reference that field.

```
<Image Source="what_to_put_here_to_make_it_work" />
```

I'm using WPF 4.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to create a static property

```
private static readonly ImageSource errorImage =
    Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(SystemIcons.Error.Handle, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

public static ImageSource ErrorImage
{
    get { return errorImage; }
}
```

and bind like this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Source={x:Static local:ErrorWindow.ErrorImage}}"/>
```