# Using a system icon as application icon in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, icons

Exactly what it says in the title, I'd like to use a specific icon from `imageres.dll` as the application icon for my WPF program.

How can this be done?

Edit: I've manually extracted the icon from the DLL, but is there a easier / more 'correct' way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that WPF can't directly handle this.
But these links may help you to find your answer:

[How do I use standard Windows warning/error icons in my WPF app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572734/how-do-i-use-standard-windows-warning-error-icons-in-my-wpf-app)

[Convert System.Drawing.Icon to System.Media.ImageSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127647/convert-system-drawing-icon-to-system-media-imagesource)

Do not forget to convert icon to Imagesource:

```
public static ImageSource ToImageSource(this Icon icon)
{
    ImageSource imageSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(
        icon.Handle,
        Int32Rect.Empty,
        BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

    return imageSource;
}
```