# Get the icon for a given extension

Tags: c#

I know i can extract a file's icon using

```
using (System.Drawing.Icon sysicon = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(filePath))
{
    icon = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(
        sysicon.Handle,
        System.Windows.Int32Rect.Empty,
        System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
}
```

But how can I, with no file, get the icon for a given extension?

Comment: Do you mean using the default icon that windows assign to your new files? Because in that case it depends on the file extension. Please give more details about what you want.

Comment: Might not be the most elegant solution (a noob solution, actually), but what I do is to create a temp empty file with the extension I want, than I use the method you showed above to get that file's icon, then I delete it. This way you don't have to access the registry, nor go into Win32 stuff.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use the `GetFileIcon` method from [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/fileicon.aspx) CodeProject article from Paul Ingles  and pass `.ext` as the `name` parameter.

The `GetFileIcon` method is a wrapper around the native [`SHGetFileInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762179(v=vs.85).aspx) and copied here for illustration:

```
public static System.Drawing.Icon GetFileIcon(string name, IconSize size, 
                                              bool linkOverlay)
{
    Shell32.SHFILEINFO shfi = new Shell32.SHFILEINFO();
    uint flags = Shell32.SHGFI_ICON | Shell32.SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES;

    if (true == linkOverlay) flags += Shell32.SHGFI_LINKOVERLAY;


    /* Check the size specified for return. */
    if (IconSize.Small == size)
    {
        flags += Shell32.SHGFI_SMALLICON ; // include the small icon flag
    } 
    else 
    {
        flags += Shell32.SHGFI_LARGEICON ;  // include the large icon flag
    }

    Shell32.SHGetFileInfo( name, 
        Shell32.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 
        ref shfi, 
        (uint) System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(shfi), 
        flags );


    // Copy (clone) the returned icon to a new object, thus allowing us 
    // to call DestroyIcon immediately
    System.Drawing.Icon icon = (System.Drawing.Icon)
                         System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(shfi.hIcon).Clone();
    User32.DestroyIcon( shfi.hIcon ); // Cleanup
    return icon;
}
```

Comment: works up to 32x32 px... not ideal for... well, anything anymore these days

Comment: This answer seems very comprehensive. Thanks for the code btw. Does this work also for extensions? Or does it need a specific file type?

Answer (score 27):

Below code is also based on [Paul Ingles solution](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2532/Obtaining-and-managing-file-and-folder-icons-using), but:

- Usable with WPF (`ImageSource` instead of `Icon`)
- Has simple caching
- Removed all stuff related to directories (I have only files in my
  case)
- Refactored using R# tips and wrapped with a single-class simple API

I've tested it on `Windows 7` and `Windows XP SP3`, it works as expected with any string as a `fileName`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

/// <summary>
/// Internals are mostly from here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2532/Obtaining-and-managing-file-and-folder-icons-using
/// Caches all results.
/// </summary>
public static class IconManager
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, ImageSource> _smallIconCache = new Dictionary<string, ImageSource>();
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, ImageSource> _largeIconCache = new Dictionary<string, ImageSource>();
    /// <summary>
    /// Get an icon for a given filename
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName">any filename</param>
    /// <param name="large">16x16 or 32x32 icon</param>
    /// <returns>null if path is null, otherwise - an icon</returns>
    public static ImageSource FindIconForFilename(string fileName, bool large)
    {
        var extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
        if (extension == null)
            return null;
        var cache = large ? _largeIconCache : _smallIconCache;
        ImageSource icon;
        if (cache.TryGetValue(extension, out icon))
            return icon;
        icon = IconReader.GetFileIcon(fileName, large ? IconReader.IconSize.Large : IconReader.IconSize.Small, false).ToImageSource();
        cache.Add(extension, icon);
        return icon;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// http://stackoverflow.com/a/6580799/1943849
    /// </summary>
    static ImageSource ToImageSource(this Icon icon)
    {
        var imageSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(
            icon.Handle,
            Int32Rect.Empty,
            BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        return imageSource;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides static methods to read system icons for both folders and files.
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>
    /// <code>IconReader.GetFileIcon("c:\\general.xls");</code>
    /// </example>
    static class IconReader
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Options to specify the size of icons to return.
        /// </summary>
        public enum IconSize
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Specify large icon - 32 pixels by 32 pixels.
            /// </summary>
            Large = 0,
            /// <summary>
            /// Specify small icon - 16 pixels by 16 pixels.
            /// </summary>
            Small = 1
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns an icon for a given file - indicated by the name parameter.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="name">Pathname for file.</param>
        /// <param name="size">Large or small</param>
        /// <param name="linkOverlay">Whether to include the link icon</param>
        /// <returns>System.Drawing.Icon</returns>
        public static Icon GetFileIcon(string name, IconSize size, bool linkOverlay)
        {
            var shfi = new Shell32.Shfileinfo();
            var flags = Shell32.ShgfiIcon | Shell32.ShgfiUsefileattributes;
            if (linkOverlay) flags += Shell32.ShgfiLinkoverlay;
            /* Check the size specified for return. */
            if (IconSize.Small == size)
                flags += Shell32.ShgfiSmallicon;
            else
                flags += Shell32.ShgfiLargeicon;
            Shell32.SHGetFileInfo(name,
                Shell32.FileAttributeNormal,
                ref shfi,
                (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(shfi),
                flags);
            // Copy (clone) the returned icon to a new object, thus allowing us to clean-up properly
            var icon = (Icon)Icon.FromHandle(shfi.hIcon).Clone();
            User32.DestroyIcon(shfi.hIcon);     // Cleanup
            return icon;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Wraps necessary Shell32.dll structures and functions required to retrieve Icon Handles using SHGetFileInfo. Code
    /// courtesy of MSDN Cold Rooster Consulting case study.
    /// </summary>
    static class Shell32
    {
        private const int MaxPath = 256;
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct Shfileinfo
        {
            private const int Namesize = 80;
            public readonly IntPtr hIcon;
            private readonly int iIcon;
            private readonly uint dwAttributes;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = MaxPath)]
            private readonly string szDisplayName;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = Namesize)]
            private readonly string szTypeName;
        };
        public const uint ShgfiIcon = 0x000000100;     // get icon
        public const uint ShgfiLinkoverlay = 0x000008000;     // put a link overlay on icon
        public const uint ShgfiLargeicon = 0x000000000;     // get large icon
        public const uint ShgfiSmallicon = 0x000000001;     // get small icon
        public const uint ShgfiUsefileattributes = 0x000000010;     // use passed dwFileAttribute
        public const uint FileAttributeNormal = 0x00000080;
        [DllImport("Shell32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr SHGetFileInfo(
            string pszPath,
            uint dwFileAttributes,
            ref Shfileinfo psfi,
            uint cbFileInfo,
            uint uFlags
            );
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Wraps necessary functions imported from User32.dll. Code courtesy of MSDN Cold Rooster Consulting example.
    /// </summary>
    static class User32
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Provides access to function required to delete handle. This method is used internally
        /// and is not required to be called separately.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hIcon">Pointer to icon handle.</param>
        /// <returns>N/A</returns>
        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern int DestroyIcon(IntPtr hIcon);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can this get Jumbo Icons?

Comment: @Nighthawk441 I'm not sure what is Jumbo Icon (big icon?). You'd better try yourself.

Comment: For the record: No, SHGetFileInfo can only return up to 32x32 px

Comment: Ideally this should pass StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase to image constructors, so that the file extension comparison is case insensitive.

Comment: Throws a `System.ArgumentException: 'Win32 handle that was passed to Icon is not valid or is the wrong type.'` occasionally. Not reliable.

Answer (score 21):

It can be done much simpler:

```
System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon("<fullPath>");
```

**Important note: it will throw an exception if the file does not exists so worth to add validation.**

Comment: Adding a note to say the file has to _exist_, but it doesn't have to be _valid_ - `Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(@"c:\temp\this_is_actually_a_text_file.xls");` will return the correct Excel icon even though the file is just a text file.

Comment: One more thing to note is that although the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.icon.extractassociatedicon?view=netframework-4.8) indicate that `fullPath` is a UNC path, in my tests the call threw on files located on network shares, even when `File.Exists()` gave them the a-ok.

Comment: Just wanted to add that this will also modify the LastAccessTime of the file ;/ im looking for a way to extract an icon but not to modify access time

Comment: @stuartd so does Windows too.... :) OP asked for icon by extension, not by actual binary type of file - I guess, this wasn't possible at all :)

Comment: In my UseCase I only had the extension itself at hand, so I created a tempfile and saved it again with my extension (I admit this would be a hell overload if there are lot of entries to iterate... ) However, after calling ExtractAssociatedIcon, I could not directly call IO.File.Delete(), since the file was still in use. So be aware of this circumstance, need some extra cleanup if using this way. :)

Answer (score 0):

Like @astef I also needed to use this for WPF, however I did require the Icons for Folders.
Since Drives and Folders don't have an extension, I utilized DirectoryInfo to determine which one is which.

For folders I always use its Closed Icon, you could however easily extend this to take Open or Closed into account.

```
/// <summary>
/// Internals are mostly from here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2532/Obtaining-and-managing-file-and-folder-icons-using
/// Caches all results.
/// </summary>
public static class IconManager
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, ImageSource> _smallIconCache = new Dictionary<string, ImageSource>();
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, ImageSource> _largeIconCache = new Dictionary<string, ImageSource>();
    /// <summary>
    /// Get an icon for a given filename
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName">any filename</param>
    /// <param name="large">16x16 or 32x32 icon</param>
    /// <returns>null if path is null, otherwise - an icon</returns>
    public static ImageSource FindIconForFilename(string fileName, bool large)
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(fileName);
        string extension = di.Extension;
        if (extension == null)
            return null;
        if (extension == string.Empty && di.Root.FullName == di.FullName) {
            extension = "ROOT";
        }
        if (extension == string.Empty && di.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory)) {
            extension = "FOLDER";
        } else {
            if (di.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory) && extension != "ROOT") {
                extension = "FOLDER";
            }
        }
        var cache = large ? _largeIconCache : _smallIconCache;
        ImageSource icon;
        if (cache.TryGetValue(extension, out icon))
            return icon;

        if (di.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory) && extension != "ROOT") {
            icon = IconReader.GetFolderIcon(fileName, large ? IconReader.IconSize.Large : IconReader.IconSize.Small, IconReader.FolderType.Closed).ToImageSource();
        } else {
            icon = IconReader.GetFileIcon(fileName, large ? IconReader.IconSize.Large : IconReader.IconSize.Small, false).ToImageSource();
        }
        if (extension != "ROOT") cache.Add(extension, icon);
        return icon;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// http://stackoverflow.com/a/6580799/1943849
    /// </summary>
    static ImageSource ToImageSource(this System.Drawing.Icon icon)
    {
        var imageSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(
            icon.Handle,
            Int32Rect.Empty,
            BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        return imageSource;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides static methods to read system icons for both folders and files.
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>
    /// <code>IconReader.GetFileIcon("c:\\general.xls");</code>
    /// </example>
    static class IconReader
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Options to specify the size of icons to return.
        /// </summary>
        public enum IconSize
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Specify large icon - 32 pixels by 32 pixels.
            /// </summary>
            Large = 0,
            /// <summary>
            /// Specify small icon - 16 pixels by 16 pixels.
            /// </summary>
            Small = 1
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns an icon for a given file - indicated by the name parameter.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="name">Pathname for file.</param>
        /// <param name="size">Large or small</param>
        /// <param name="linkOverlay">Whether to include the link icon</param>
        /// <returns>System.Drawing.Icon</returns>
        public static System.Drawing.Icon GetFileIcon(string name, IconSize size, bool linkOverlay)
        {
            var shfi = new Shell32.SHFILEINFO();
            var flags = Shell32.SHGFI_ICON;
            if (linkOverlay) flags += Shell32.SHGFI_LINKOVERLAY;
            /* Check the size specified for return. */
            if (IconSize.Small == size)
                flags += Shell32.SHGFI_SMALLICON;
            else
                flags += Shell32.SHGFI_SMALLICON;
            Shell32.SHGetFileInfo(name,
                Shell32.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                ref shfi,
                (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(shfi),
                flags);
            // Copy (clone) the returned icon to a new object, thus allowing us to clean-up properly
            var icon = (System.Drawing.Icon)System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(shfi.hIcon).Clone();
            User32.DestroyIcon(shfi.hIcon);     // Cleanup
            return icon;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Options to specify whether folders should be in the open or closed state.
        /// </summary>
        public enum FolderType
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Specify open folder.
            /// </summary>
            Open = 0,
            /// <summary>
            /// Specify closed folder.
            /// </summary>
            Closed = 1
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Used to access system folder icons.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="size">Specify large or small icons.</param>
        /// <param name="folderType">Specify open or closed FolderType.</param>
        /// <returns>System.Drawing.Icon</returns>
        public static System.Drawing.Icon GetFolderIcon(string name, IconSize size, FolderType folderType)
        {
            // Need to add size check, although errors generated at present!
            uint flags = Shell32.SHGFI_ICON | Shell32.SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX;

            if (FolderType.Open == folderType) {
                flags += Shell32.SHGFI_OPENICON;
            }

            if (IconSize.Small == size) {
                flags += Shell32.SHGFI_SMALLICON;
            } else {
                flags += Shell32.SHGFI_LARGEICON;
            }

            // Get the folder icon
            Shell32.SHFILEINFO shfi = new Shell32.SHFILEINFO();
            Shell32.SHGetFileInfo(name,
                Shell32.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY,
                ref shfi,
                (uint)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(shfi),
                flags);

            System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(shfi.hIcon); // Load the icon from an HICON handle

            // Now clone the icon, so that it can be successfully stored in an ImageList
            System.Drawing.Icon icon = (System.Drawing.Icon)System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(shfi.hIcon).Clone();

            User32.DestroyIcon(shfi.hIcon);     // Cleanup
            return icon;
        }
    }
}
/// <summary>
/// Wraps necessary Shell32.dll structures and functions required to retrieve Icon Handles using SHGetFileInfo. Code
/// courtesy of MSDN Cold Rooster Consulting case study.
/// </summary>
public class Shell32
{

    public const int MAX_PATH = 256;
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SHITEMID
    {
        public ushort cb;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]
        public byte[] abID;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct ITEMIDLIST
    {
        public SHITEMID mkid;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct BROWSEINFO
    {
        public IntPtr hwndOwner;
        public IntPtr pidlRoot;
        public IntPtr pszDisplayName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
        public string lpszTitle;
        public uint ulFlags;
        public IntPtr lpfn;
        public int lParam;
        public IntPtr iImage;
    }

    // Browsing for directory.
    public const uint BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS = 0x0001;
    public const uint BIF_DONTGOBELOWDOMAIN = 0x0002;
    public const uint BIF_STATUSTEXT = 0x0004;
    public const uint BIF_RETURNFSANCESTORS = 0x0008;
    public const uint BIF_EDITBOX = 0x0010;
    public const uint BIF_VALIDATE = 0x0020;
    public const uint BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE = 0x0040;
    public const uint BIF_USENEWUI = (BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE | BIF_EDITBOX);
    public const uint BIF_BROWSEINCLUDEURLS = 0x0080;
    public const uint BIF_BROWSEFORCOMPUTER = 0x1000;
    public const uint BIF_BROWSEFORPRINTER = 0x2000;
    public const uint BIF_BROWSEINCLUDEFILES = 0x4000;
    public const uint BIF_SHAREABLE = 0x8000;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SHFILEINFO
    {
        public const int NAMESIZE = 80;
        public IntPtr hIcon;
        public int iIcon;
        public uint dwAttributes;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = MAX_PATH)]
        public string szDisplayName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = NAMESIZE)]
        public string szTypeName;
    };

    public const uint SHGFI_ICON = 0x000000100;     // get icon
    public const uint SHGFI_DISPLAYNAME = 0x000000200;     // get display name
    public const uint SHGFI_TYPENAME = 0x000000400;     // get type name
    public const uint SHGFI_ATTRIBUTES = 0x000000800;     // get attributes
    public const uint SHGFI_ICONLOCATION = 0x000001000;     // get icon location
    public const uint SHGFI_EXETYPE = 0x000002000;     // return exe type
    public const uint SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX = 0x000004000;     // get system icon index
    public const uint SHGFI_LINKOVERLAY = 0x000008000;     // put a link overlay on icon
    public const uint SHGFI_SELECTED = 0x000010000;     // show icon in selected state
    public const uint SHGFI_ATTR_SPECIFIED = 0x000020000;     // get only specified attributes
    public const uint SHGFI_LARGEICON = 0x000000000;     // get large icon
    public const uint SHGFI_SMALLICON = 0x000000001;     // get small icon
    public const uint SHGFI_OPENICON = 0x000000002;     // get open icon
    public const uint SHGFI_SHELLICONSIZE = 0x000000004;     // get shell size icon
    public const uint SHGFI_PIDL = 0x000000008;     // pszPath is a pidl
    public const uint SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES = 0x000000010;     // use passed dwFileAttribute
    public const uint SHGFI_ADDOVERLAYS = 0x000000020;     // apply the appropriate overlays
    public const uint SHGFI_OVERLAYINDEX = 0x000000040;     // Get the index of the overlay

    public const uint FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY = 0x00000010;
    public const uint FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL = 0x00000080;

    [DllImport("Shell32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SHGetFileInfo(
                  string pszPath,
                  uint dwFileAttributes,
                  ref SHFILEINFO psfi,
                  uint cbFileInfo,
                  uint uFlags
                  );
}
/// <summary>
/// Wraps necessary functions imported from User32.dll. Code courtesy of MSDN Cold Rooster Consulting example.
/// </summary>
static class User32
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides access to function required to delete handle. This method is used internally
    /// and is not required to be called separately.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hIcon">Pointer to icon handle.</param>
    /// <returns>N/A</returns>
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern int DestroyIcon(IntPtr hIcon);
}
```

}