# Transferring binary data using sockets?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I am thinking of making a server/client application that does this: the client(s) will connect to the server and the server will send back a list of folders (probably music or videos) that the client will be able to stream or download. I am going to make a GUI for this so that it won't be a text-only interface. I want it so that when the client connects to the server and gets the information about the media files that can be streamed/downloaded, the client will show the folders/files in an explorer-like interface (folders will show up with a folder icon, videos will show up with a video icon, etc.)

This seems really big to me but I really want to learn more about socket programming with C# and feel that getting my hands really dirty is the best way. As you can imagine, I have a lot of confusion about how to start this and what it is that I need to do to make this work.

The first part of my question is: If I want to let a client receive a list of files/folders and also have the ability to download/stream them, do I need to do something with transferring binary data using sockets or am I completely wrong on that? If I'm wrong, do I need to use something else like file readers and somehow use them over sockets?

The second part to my question is: when I transfer this information over to a client, how can I make the client show the appropriate icons for videos, folders, mp3s, etc.? I'm thinking that if I have to transfer binary data I will have to use that data to somehow populate the client GUI with the correct icons/data. I am stuck on exactly how to handle that. Are there certain methods/classes that I can use to parse that data and do what I want to do with it? Again, I don't know if I'm wrong about needing to transfer binary data but either way I am confused on what it is that's necessary to handle this.

I apologize if any of my terminology is wrong. I am obviously not an expert in C# yet ;)

Comment: Getting a file icon:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701263/get-the-icon-for-a-given-extension

Comment: Wow, thanks! Guess I should explore the .NET framework a little more...

Comment: You're welcome.  That, and explore StackOverflow - if there's a common programming problem that needs solving, it'll probably already be here - Enjoy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any time you are sending data between machines (or between processes), you are already talking binary data (you could argue that *everything* is binary data, but when working with it as an OO model it doesn't feel like it). The point here is that all you need to do is *serialize your messages*. There are a myriad of serialization frameworks - some aimed at convenience, some aimed to range-of-features, and som can use aimed at performance (minimum bandwidth etc).

Even the inbuilt ones would work - for example, you can use `XmlSerializer` etc to write to a `Stream` (such as the `NetworkStream` you typically use with a socket). But please - not `BinaryFormatter` (it will hurt you, honest). Personally I'd use something a bit less verbose such as protobuf-net, but I'm somewhat biased since I wrote it ;p

However, note that when working with sockets, you are typically sending multiple (separate) messages as part of the conversation. In order for each end to correctly and conveniently read the right data *per-message* from the stream, it is common to prefix each message with the length (number of bytes) - for example, as a little-endian `int` taking a fixed 4 bytes. So the reading process is:

- read 4 bytes
- interpret that as an `int`, let's say `n`
- read `n` bytes
- run that data through your deserializer, perhaps via `MemoryStream`
- process the message

and the sending process might be:

- serialize the message, perhaps to a `MemoryStream`
- query the length and form the 4 byte prefix
- write the prefix
- write the data

Comment: Thanks Marc, this answered a bunch of my outstanding questions :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to go to as low level as Socket, unless you just want to learn of course.

I suggest using WCF. It will completely meet your requirements, will be flexible and you will not have to deal with sockets directly.

WCF is a big framework, but you can quickly learn how to use it.

[Introduction to WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx)

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/fileicon.aspx) you can find how to retrieve and show file icon in Windows.
If you client is hosted by Windows, you don't need to transfer icons, you can just retrieve image on the client by filename/extension.

Comment: Thanks for you recommendation. I thought of maybe picking up WCF, but I think that I'd still like to have the knowledge and experience of how things work at the socket level. I may take your suggestion and go with WCF, but I am still having a really difficult time of wrapping my head around how all of this kind of stuff would work over a network. All these different types of data, protocols, and structures are confusing me. I haven't done much programming with projects that work over the internet...

Comment: @Aaron - Socket is not difficult, especially if you use TCP. It is just sending raw bytes back and forth between client and server. However, what is more difficult is to format and parse data, make sure you resend/reconnect properly, and many other low level issues. WCF solves those issues for you, and you can focus on business logic and requirements instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I see. Is WCF generally the standard nowadays? Is using sockets in C# considered "old" or "deprecated" these days?

Comment: @Aaron - WCF is kind of a standard. It allows you to abstract you business logic from how data a transferred between peers. You can set WCF to transfer data vias SOAP, or MSMQ or net-tcp in your case without changing code, just changing settings file. If you use net-tcp binding it will use Socket underneath. However, you can't say that WCF replaces Sockets. There are legit cases to use Socket, but this is definitely not your case.

Comment: Okay, great. Thanks very much again for all of your help on this!

Comment: @Aaron - just to say: there are many opinions on this subject. Personally, I appreciate that WCF is *convenient*, but the trade-off there is that it is pretty bloated - you get a *significant* amount of overhead on your data. Sockets are still very much in usage too. Either is a valid choice.