# How to read Excel with notepad text file inside it C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a notepad file pasted inside one of the columns in excel.I am trying to read Excel to a datatable,while accessing its reading only text,ignoring the notepad attachment part.I need to display notepad as attachment in the UI.How do I do this? [image: AttachedImageForReference]

Comment: What UI? WinForms? WPF? You tagged MVC - so is it ASP.NET? ... What controls are you using right now?

Comment: I do not know what you mean by notepad file because if you open any fle extension with notepad, it becomes a notepad file. What is the extension of the file attached as a link in your excel spreadsheet?

Comment: Is it related to this question maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/q/2701263/982149 Are you looking for the default-app icon for the file type (by extension)?

Comment: @Fildor Its a mvc web application.@phael please refer attached image

Comment: The only way I can think of that you'd get access to this would be via the rich application object model of Excel, since the embedding is effectively good-old OLE. But using the Excel Automation API from asp.net is a no-no, so I can't see a way forward here.