# Display WinForm Image in WPF application

Tags: wpf, winforms, image, xaml, dll

I have a dll with quite a bit of System.Drawing.Image resources that I have wrapped into static properties so I can update them dynamically.

I would like to use the images through xaml in a WPF application, but the only way I can figure is to do it through the code behind manually.

Is there a way to do the winform to wpf image convertion on a static property in xaml?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could bind to your images directly, using a converter. Here is an example in a window:

```
<Window.Resources>
   <WinForms2WPFImageConverter x:Key="WF2WPFDrawingConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

...

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127647/convert-system-drawing-icon-to-system-media-imagesource) has a drawing converter, which I adapted here as a ValueConverter.

```
public class WinForms2WPFImageConverter : IValueConverter {

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {

        System.Drawing.Image i = (System.Drawing.Image) value;   
        using (MemoryStream drawingStream = new MemoryStream())
        {

            i.Save(drawingStream);

            i.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            return System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.Create(drawingStream);
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

Of course, you need to account for namespaces in the declaration of the resource.

I advise not using static properties, in order to leverage INotifyPropertyChanged (or dependency properties), so that the display automatically changes when the properties point to other images.

(note: this was typed, not copied from VS, so there may be a syntax error somewhere.)

Answer (score 1):

You could bind to your images using a Method in WPF. Here is an example in a link

http://microsoftdotnetsolutions.blogspot.com/2016/07/convert-winforms-image-to-wpf.html

Comment: While the commenting limitations while not having enough reputations are understandable, please refrain from posting comments as answers. If you know you have an answer to this question, please, elaborate it and write it respecting the [StackOverflow guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for writing good answers.

Comment: Although the limitations on commenting while not having enough reputation are understandable, please refrain from posting comments as answers. If you know you have an answer to this question, please, edit it, elaborate it respecting the [StackOverflow guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for writing good answers.