# ImageSource for Icon property must be an icon file - Embedded Resource

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, embedded-resource, resx

I need to assign an `Icon` to a WPF window, but cannot seem to do this from a resource file. I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127647/convert-system-drawing-icon-to-system-media-imagesource), but end up with:

> ImageSource for Icon property must be an icon file

But, if I try to leave it as `Icon`, then I get an error that I need to convert to `ImageSource`...

```
Icon = Properties.Resources.myIcon.ToImageSource();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

```
using (var iconStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    icon.Save(iconStream);
    iconStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return BitmapFrame.Create(iconStream);
}
```

which was actually one of the unaccepted answers from the same question I already referenced: [just a different response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4031232/779513)

Answer (score 0):

The other SO solution you reference is creating an icon from an IntPtr and so does not apply to your situation.  Instead try the following:

```
var icon = BitmapFrame.Create(Application.GetResourceStream(
              new Uri("MyAppIcon.ico", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)).Stream);
```

http://welearndotnet.blogspot.com/2011_11_21_archive.html

Comment: I am reading from a .resx file, though. I would prefer the strong typing that I gain from that. Or, do I have to reference the file location?