# Is it possible to use WinForm icon resource in WPF?

Tags: wpf, winforms, icons, embedded-resource

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert System.Drawing.Icon to System.Media.ImageSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127647/convert-system-drawing-icon-to-system-media-imagesource)

I have a WPF app. To display tray icon, I referenced WinForm assemblies and added a few icons to resource, they can be accessed like `Properties.Resources.MyIcon` with type `System.Drawing.Icon`. I'd like to display these icons in my main window as well. My question is whether it is possible to directly use these WinForm icons in WPF Image control?

Comment: This previous [answer][1] seems to be exactly what you need.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127647/convert-system-drawing-icon-to-system-media-imagesource

Comment: @bouvierr exactly what I want. I have voted to close my question as dupe. Thanks for the information.