# Access project files from class in separate folder

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

### Screenshots below are from the Solution Explorer Pane:

---

I have a class in Folder **DataAccess** that needs to access a resource in Folder **data**. I get the following error message.

`System.IO.IOException: Cannot locate resource 'data/danio_rerio.xml'.`

### Does not Work If:

[image: Does not Work]

### It works if:

[image: It works]

Folder **data** is a child folder within Folder **DataAccess**. Is it possible for me to use the following syntax:

`foldername/somefile.someextension`

to access resources within the project that are in seperate folders?

---

Edit: I do not want to hard code locations to my directories.

Comment: What is the "Deployment" setting for these files.  Generally resources are bundled into your assembly at compile-time, and then accessed through a `ResourceStream` rather than a `FileStream`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself. Should have searched more before offering a bounty -_-

[Pack URIs in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx#Programming_with_Pack_URIs) [[Source]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74466/how-do-i-use-an-icon-that-is-a-resource-in-wpf)

Answer (score 2):

When you run your application, the running directory becomes your "active directory"

Suppose you have

`c:\myproject\bin\debug\myapp.exe`

When you run the application you try to search

`c:\myproject\bin\debug\foldername\somefile.someextension`

what you actually want could be close to

`c:\myproject\data\daniorenio.xml`

so you'll want to search the following directory

`c:\myproject\bin\debug\..\..\data\daniorenio.xml`

The `..` operator tells that you want to go back in the directory hierarchy

However this is assuming your binary will be in a lower branch than your ressource. What I actually do is copy everything I absolutely need for runtime inside a special directory such as

`c:\myproject\RuntimeRequired`

This way I can issue a post build event like this (In Project/Properties/Build-Events/Post-Build)

copy /Y "$(ProjectDir)RuntimeRequired*" "$(OutDir)"