# Getting Icon from ResourceStream

Tags: c#, wpf, stream, icons, notifyicon

I have a Icon.ico and in the Properties the Build Action is "Resource"...

I want to load that Icon in the Application..

I did something like this:

```
Icon theIcon = new Icon(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("MyNameSpace.Icon.ico"));
```

that didnt worked (it says "**Value of 'null' is not valid for 'stream'**.")

What can I do?

Comment: This should help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74466/how-do-i-use-an-icon-that-is-a-resource-in-wpf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try using [Application.GetResourceStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms596994%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method

```
using(Stream stream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("/MyNameSpace.ico")).Stream)
{
    Icon myIcon = new System.Drawing.Icon(stream);
}
```

more information from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970494.aspx)

Comment: Thanks I think that would work also well... I did this: `Stream iconStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/INBOS_Starter;component/Inbos_Starter_Icon.ico")).Stream;`