# How can I set a dynamic resource path?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to access my resources this way:

```
string iconVar = "20";
imgIcon.Image = "Properties.Resources." + iconVar;
```

This is not possible because I give a string and not an image.

So the question is, how can I access the resources without giving the name of the resource in the code?

I know normally you should use

```
imgIcon.Image = Properties.Resources.image1;
```

The thing is, I don't know yet if it's gonna be image1 or image 2 that I'm gonna use.

I tried this:

```
imgIcon.ImageLocation = "pack://application:,,,/project1;component/Properties.Resources._" + iconVar;
imgIcon.Refresh();
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873453/getting-icon-from-resourcestream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you do not know yet what image you will use, why is this? And is there a reason you want to determine what image you want based on a string?

If you plan on setting the images based on certain conditions, you could try this instead of working with a string:

```
Image image1 = Properties.Resources.image1;
Image image2 = Properties.Resources.image2;

imgIcon.Image = someBool ? image1 : image2;
```

If you have not decided yet what image you want for the final version and you want to easily change it everywhere in your code simultaneously, define the image as a global variable and use the variable.

**Edit:**

To load an image based on the name of said image, you could try the following (not tested myself, but taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592150/load-image-from-resources) answer):

```
imgIcon.Image = (Image)Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("20");
```

Comment: In my resources I have icon 1 till icon 500. Via a web request (json) I get the number of which icon I'm gonna use. Then I want to display that icon in a picturebox. I could use 500 cases. But that's not really clean. Hope I explained enough. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: @FCJesse Have a look at the update, I added a way of loading a resource based on a string.

Answer (score 0):

I'll make a few assumptions:

- you're using `WinForms`
- you've already added the image to your project resources as an "image"
- the `imgIcon` control is a `PictureBox`

If that's all true, then you should be able to assign it directly.

```
imgIcon.Image = Properties.Resources.YourImageName
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "without giving the name of the resource". If you want to specify an image, you'll have to give its name.

Comment: Sorry for not enough information. That's basically it. But the thing is, I don't know if I want to use YourImageName1 or YourImageName2.

Comment: I know. What I mean is, I have a string, the string is the name of the resource. The string is called iconVar. iconVar can either be image1, image2.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about wpf, I think you need something like this:

```
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.BeginInit();
bi.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/YourApplicationName;component/Properties.Resources."+iconVar, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
bi.EndInit();
imgIcon.Image.Source = bi;
```

make sure to replace *YourApplicationName* with your actual application name (the name of the assembly/exe)

Comment: I'm using WinForms so I did this:


imgIcon.ImageLocation = "pack://application:,,,/project1;component/Properties.Resources._" + iconVar;

It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I only used the trick with the "pack://". I didn't copy his code.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.
This is the code I used:

```
Assembly _assembly;
Stream _imageStream;
_assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
_imageStream = _assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("project.Resources._" + iconVar + ".png");
imgIcon.Image = new Bitmap(_imageStream);
```

Thanks you for your responses!