# Resources icon not working

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to add my icon as tay icon.

But this error is shown.

**xaml.cs:**

private System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon _notifyIcon;
[image]

**This icon already added on resources but not working.**

When I writing codes then resources file name not be shown.

**See:**

[image]

**How can I solve this problem?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use an icon that is a resource in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74466/how-do-i-use-an-icon-that-is-a-resource-in-wpf)

Comment: First, always show code instead of images. Second, it should work just fine as long as you added the icon trough the resource interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Stream

```
Stream iconStream = Application.GetResourceStream( 
            new Uri( "pack://application:,,,/YourReferencedAssembly;component/YourPossibleSubFolder/YourResourceFile.ico" )).Stream;
            notifyIcon.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(iconStream);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use it that way - don't add the image to the .resx file. Right click on the project -> Properties -> Resources -> Add Resource -> Add existing file...
Add the image there. If you do this you should be able to get it in the code through `Properties.Resources.MyIcon`

Comment: *(You can just drag and drop the icon or image file in the resource window) will work just fine*

Answer (score 0):

You just need to have an existing file, open the context menu on your folder , and then choose Add => Existing item...[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzea2.png),name the folder **Images**

You need to change your image's property "Build Action" to Content  and change the Copy to "If Newer" or "Always"

It will create a folder in bin\debug every time you build your application.

Then give your path like this `@"Images\"`