# Can you change an icon of a notifyIcon programatically?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a WinForms app that has a little setup program that writes to Properties.Settings. The user needs to choose his notifyIcon icon from his hard drive. I can't just change it with

```
notifyIcon1.Icon = Properties.Settings.Default.userIcon;
```

because it throws up

> "Cannot convert from "string" to "System.Drawing.Icon".

Can somebody correct me?

Comment: Try checking this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74466/how-do-i-use-an-icon-that-is-a-resource-in-wpf
Even though it's WPF, it explains how to get System.Drawing.Icon object when given path.

Comment: `Icon icon = new Icon(@"Properties.Settings.Default.userIcon", [The Icon Size, Eventually]);`

Comment: Jimi, your solution worked! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

"The user needs to choose his notifyIcon icon from his hard drive".

Is the icon in a filename somewhere? If the user selects an icon from the hard driver, does he in fact select a file that contains an icon?

If that is the case, you should define `Properties.Settings.Default.UserIcon` as a string and save the name of the filename. Give your window a property that gets and sets the UserIcon.

```
private string UserIconFileName
{
    get => Properties.Settings.Default.UserIcon;
    set => properties.Settings.Default.UserIcon = value;
}

private Icon LoadUserIcon
{
    string userIconFileName = this.UserIconFileName
    if (!File.Exists(userIconFileName))
    {
        // TODO: decide what to do if there is no such file
    }
    else
    {
        return new Icon(userIconFileName);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to Save your properties when closing the program:

```
private void OnFormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```