# WPF Registered as Startup program but could not find icon file

Tags: c#, wpf, notifyicon

I registered some WPF from as startup like this

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
Assembly curAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
key.SetValue(curAssembly.GetName().Name, Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
```

and register NotifyIcon like this

```
HandyOrderPOSIcon = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon();
HandyOrderPOSIcon.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon("Icon.ico");
HandyOrderPOSIcon.Visible = true;
HandyOrderPOSIcon.ContextMenuStrip = menuStrip;
HandyOrderPOSIcon.MouseClick += delegate (object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        {
          menuStrip.Show();
        }
      };
```

When restart Windows, it throw a Exception like this

[image: fileio exception]

but when execute this program manually, it works without this exception.

Comment: looks like the working directory is different from when you run the executable manually , check out this thread [](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822951/use-registry-to-startup-a-program-and-also-change-the-current-working-directory)

Comment: It would be better to load icon file from resources. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74671/3137337

Comment: @emoacht I resolved this problem like this `HandyOrderPOSIcon = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon();
      Stream iconStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("MyProgramNamespace.Icon.ico");

      HandyOrderPOSIcon.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(iconStream)` Thx!